# How to read a Map inside another Map, in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm new to Java, so sorry if this is pretty obvious, but I can't quite understand how to work with 2 HashMaps inside each other
I have my main, where I want to add some words to a Map, and then, I want to read them:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dicionario d = new Dicionario();
    d.add("english", "BOOK", "Book");
    d.add("french", "BOOK", "livre");
    d.add("portuguese", "BOOK", "livro");
    d.add("english", "YEAR", "year");
    d.add("french", "YEAR", "an");
    d.add("portuguese", "YEAR", "ano");
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

This Map, has another Map inside him:

```
private Map<String, Map<String, String> > dic = new HashMap<>();
```

Then I add those words:

```
protected void add(String s1, String s2, String s3){

    Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();

    m.put(s2, s3);
    dic.put(s1, m);

}
```

And redefine the function toString to read them, but only appears 1 value per key:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    String s= "";

    for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String,String>> entry : dic.entrySet())
    {
        s += "\"" + entry.getKey() + "\": ";



        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 : dic.get(entry.getKey()).entrySet())
        {
            s+=entry2.getKey() + "->" + entry2.getValue() + "\t";

        }
        s+="\n";
    }

    return s;
}
```

Why is that? I am looking at this like if it was a bidimensional array, but with 2 values (key, value) in each position.

How can I do to show all the values that the keys from the first map have?

Thanks, and sorry for such a basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your add method to following

```
protected void add(String s1, String s2, String s3) {
    Map<String, String> m = null;
    m = dic.get(s1);
    if (m == null) {
        m = new HashMap<>();
    }
    m.put(s2, s3);
    dic.put(s1, m);
}
```

Comment: I really thought that     `dic.put(s1,m)` would point the beginning of the other map to the key s1, without the need to use `dic.get(s1)`. Thank you :)

Comment: In your original code, you were doing     Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
 which was resetting the hashmap. Its kinda tricky to imagine map inside a hashmap. Good question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your `add(String, String, String)` method, you are instancing a new `HashMap` each time so you overwrite the previously instanced `HashMap` from a previous call.

You should update your method this way:

```
protected void add(String s1, String s2, String s3){
    Map<String, String> m = dic.get(s1);

    if (m == null) {
        m = new HashMap<>();
        dic.put(s1, m);
    }

    m.put(s2, s3);
}
```

To avoid having to manage this by hand yourself, I suggest that you use [Guava's `Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) data structure (more specifically [`HashBasedTable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html)).

Comment: Wouldn't `dic.get(s1)` throw a NullPointerException ?

Comment: From the docs: V get(Object key)
Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object))

Comment: However this solution also overrides the previous stored value doesn't it? OP is adding repeated keys. What he probably wants is a `Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>` where you have `{ word_key, [ { language1, word_in_language1}, { language2, word_in_language2 } ]`

Comment: From the examples OP has given, it seems pretty safe to assume that (s1, s2) combinations are unique.

Comment: Yes, the combinations of (s1,s2) are always unique. This is just an exercise about making a poor dictionary, in which word, has only one translation :p Thank you